# OpenOffice basic: declaring an array constant

Tags: arrays, vba, openoffice-calc

I know this must be stupid, but I really did a lot of search on this site, apache.org and googled a lot, but I still ain't able to do something like

```
const indRangeNumbers(5) = {7,7,12,6,8}
```

Error: syntax

```
global indRangeNumbers (5) = Array {7,7,12,6,8}
```

Error: , expected

or even

```
global indRangeNumbers() as variant
sub assignArrays()
    indRangeNumbers = Array  {7,7,12,6,8}
end sub
```

Comment: Try `Array(7,7,12,6,8)` - at least that's the VBA syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign to a Variant variable which will contain a single Array object, so no need for ().

```vb
Global indRangeNumbers As Variant
Sub assignArrays()
    indRangeNumbers = Array(7,7,12,6,8)
End Sub
```

An example is at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=46161.  Also see the DevGuide for how to initialize arrays at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Basic/Mapping_of_Sequences_and_Arrays.